# Laravel "PHP Artisan route:list" fails with Target class [App\Http\Controllers\API\Auth\LoginController] does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

When executing the command "php artisan route:list" if receive this message:

```
   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  : Target class [App\Http\Controllers\API\Auth\LoginController] does not exist.

  at /mnt/c/Sources/wachtweken.nl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:805
    801|
    802|         try {
    803|             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    804|         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  > 805|             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    806|         }
    807|
    808|         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    809|         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console\{closure}()
      [internal]:0

  2   ReflectionException::("Class App\Http\Controllers\API\Auth\LoginController does not exist")
      /mnt/c/Sources/wachtweken.nl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:803
```

I understand that the system can't find a class in App\Http\Controllers\API\Auth\LoginController
because it's located in
App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController

Where does he get the info from that's stored in App\Http\Controllers\API\Auth\LoginController ?

A lot of topics are giving "php artisan config:cache" as solution but that doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that in the `web.php` there was a line in the API namespace:

```
Route::get('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

That shouldn't be there. That solved the error.

Comment: Mark your answer as best

Comment: That can only done after two days (according to the popup i received when clicking on the check.